# "Cordova build android" error on Linux: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set

Tags: cordova, android-build

I'm just getting started with Cordova, and I was able to build & run the "hello" application on both Linux and Max.
I then tried to wrap an existing project by creating an empty project (using the cli) and copying the app files into the "www" folder.
This worked on the Mac/iOS, and I was able to build & run, but the same app fails to build on my Linux box for Android.

build output excerpt:

```
-package:
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
[apkbuilder] Creating Testapp-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
BUILD FAILED
/scratch/msmith/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:962: 
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/scratch/msmith/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:973: 
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/scratch/msmith/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:312: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Failed to add /scratch/msmith/test/cordova/testapp/platforms/android/bin/Testapp.ap_
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.addZipFile(ApkBuilder.java:547)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:453)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:394)
    at com.android.ant.ApkBuilderTask.execute(ApkBuilderTask.java:334)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
<I removed several lines here>
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:193)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.writeEntry(SignedJarBuilder.java:311)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.writeZip(SignedJarBuilder.java:244)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.addZipFile(ApkBuilder.java:540)
```

The file mentioned above has a size of 58760445.
Failed to add /scratch/msmith/test/cordova/testapp/platforms/android/bin/Testapp.ap_
(I upgraded my version of info-zip to a 3.1 beta, and got the same error).